# Direct payment using PayPal Express Checkout library for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, paypal

I have been using paypal express checkout library to purchase some items from iPhone application which I developed. By using MECL (Mobile Express checkout library), Paypal will be asking the user to enter the credentials of his/her account. What if the users dont have an account in Paypal. So, In this regard, I would like to introduce "Direct payment" using credit/debit card apart from login approach.

So, how can I update my MECL which supports for Direct Payment also.

Comment: What are these "items" you are selling? If they are some in app functionality or online service etc then you won't be able to use PayPal for this. You must use In-App purchases.

Answer (score 1):

From the App Store Guidelines:

11.2
Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

11.3
Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected

is your app for jail broken phones? If not you will not get your app through review.

Comment: He didn't say if he was selling physical goods or not. If he is, then he's okay

Comment: I can see you are correct that the rules I spotted do not address his specific situation. How about this one then:
11.13
Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Comment: No, I see that 11.13 is specifically about content used in app also.

Comment: Yes basically, if you *can* use in-app purchase, then that's your only option. In-App purchases doesn't cover real goods, so that's the loophole if you will, or at least, there's an opportunity to use another payment solution.